# Reference for function defined inside an object

Tags: scala, reflection

How do I get reference for a `def` defined inside a `object`.

```
object SomeObject {
  def someMethod(x: String): String = s"Hello $x"
}
```

I want reference for `someMethod` function.

What I tried so far:

```
val method = SomeObject.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.head
val function = method _
```

But this returns `() => java.lang.reflect.Method = <function0>` instead of `(String) => (String) = <function1>`.

**EDIT:**
I don't know the method names here, first I need to retrieve all method names and then get reference for them. For simplicity I have used only one method in `SomeObject`.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Just do it directly

```
object SomeObject {
  def someMethod(x: String): String = s"Hello $x"
}
val f = SomeObject.someMethod _       //> f  : String => String = <function1>
f("World")                            //> res0: String = Hello World
```

Comment: I don't know the method names here, first I need to retrieve all method names and then get reference for them. For simplicity I have used only one method in `SomeObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a `Method` object and you know the method it corresponds to has 1 argument, you just write `method.invoke(SomeObject, _)` (`method.invoke(SomeObject, _, _)` for 2 arguments and so on). Note that you'll get an `Object => Object` function which will throw an exception when passed anything but `String`, not `String => String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: 
`val function = method.invoke(SomeObject, _: String)`

Comment: Yes I can use that, but I don't the type of argument the method is accepting, I have generate it at runtime.

Comment: @PravinGadakh, can you expand on your use-case? You're doing something that seems likely to always be tricky/fragile. Even when you know the type of the argument, how will you generate the right value of that type?